# How to post naked parameter in no JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I need to post some parameter data. This should be a simple naked string without json object. I do this i have success but parameter is not saveing.

```
var offerMsg = $('.js-offerMsg').val();
$.post(url, ("message", offerMsg));
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ shows that the second argument (data) needs to be a string.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the call as follows:

```
$.post(url, {message: offerMsg});
```

This will send a form-encoded POST:

```
POST /path HTTP 1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Length: 10
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

message=hi
```

If you want to send something that's not form-encoded, you won't be able to use `$.post`, as you can't override the `contentType` parameter, even when sending a raw string. You'd need to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: offerMsg,
    contentType: "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
});
```

which would result in:

```
POST /path HTTP 1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

hi
```

Comment: You'll have to explain what you mean by that. Can you update your question with the structure of data you expect to be POSTed, and how the POST request is being handled server-side? `message=hi` is the standard way of encoding data POSTed from a form with a field called `message`.

Comment: yeah, where to define this message field?

Comment: That still doesn't explain your question. What do you mean define it? The first example sends a POST with `message=hi`. If you're using PHP for instance, that will then exist in the request as `$_POST['message']`.